Angular 14 popup video play after closing the popup video play in background
I am working on Angular 14. I have a button. When user click on button i am showing the video in popup modal. But when i click on outside of the popup the popup is closing but video is keep playing in background how to resolve issue:
I have added this code in the page builder for playing video in the popup
component.html
<div class="intro-video">
<div class="hepVideos">
  <label>Learn More : </label>
  <img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Help Video" (click)="videoPlay()"
    src="../../../assets/videos/absenceblueprint_thumbnail.png" class="help_thumbnail" />
</div>
<div *ngIf="isVideoActive === 'false'" class="modal fade" [ngClass]="{'show': isHelpVideoActive}" id="myModal"
  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
  [ngStyle]="{'display': isHelpVideoStyle}">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeHelpVideo()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="embed-responsive-item">
          <video #videoPlayer id="video-player" width="640" autoplay height="360" controls preload="metadata"
            [src]="videoSource" loop >
            <track id="video-track" label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en"
              src="../../../assets/videos/subtitles.vtt" default>
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

component.ts file
closeHelpVideo(): void {


const video: HTMLVideoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
var listaFrames: any = document.getElementById('video-player');
var trackFrame: any = document.getElementById('video-track');



let videoFrame:any = document.querySelectorAll("video");

localStorage.setItem('hideWatchVideos', 'true');

this.isHelpVideoActive = false;
this.isHelpVideoStyle = 'none';

this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.pause();
this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.currentTime = 0;
this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.muted = true;
this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.autoplay = false;
this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.loop = false;
// this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.currentSrc = null;
// this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.remove();
this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.load = false;
// video.currentSrc  = "";
listaFrames.audio = false;
listaFrames.loop = false;
// listaFrames[0].currentSrc = "";
videoFrame[0].src ="";
videoFrame[0].pause();
videoFrame[0].muted = true;

listaFrames.remove();
listaFrames.pause();   

this.videoSource = "";
// listaFrames.src = "";
// listaFrames.removeAttribute('src');
// listaFrames.load();
// listaFrames.pause();


listaFrames.currentTime = 0;
listaFrames.pause();
listaFrames.removeAttribute('src'); // video.src = '' works so this line can be deleted
// listaFrames.load();
listaFrames.src = '';
listaFrames.srcObject = null;
listaFrames.remove()

// trackFrame.pause();
trackFrame.removeAttribute('src'); // video.src = '' works so this line can be deleted
// trackFrame.load();
trackFrame.src = '';
trackFrame.srcObject = null;
trackFrame.remove()

}

is this bootstrap-4? if you're manually opening the modal, then what's closing it..? you might include modal and video method related code
